# How to implement Loading Incrementally (ItemAppearing) Items in ListView using MVVM in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am having a `ListView` in which items are added incrementally using `ItemAppearing`. I want it to implement it through my **ViewModel**. `ItemAppearing` only calls a method from **View.cs** hence, is there any way I could implement it in my **ViewModel** class.

Please note that I can load incrementally items when adding it from **View.cs**. I just want to load more items from ViewModel.

**Here is my XAML code:**

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding JobsList}" HasUnevenRows="True" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedJob}" ItemAppearing="LoadMoreItems">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: this function is builtin to CollectionView - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#load-data-incrementally

Comment: @Jason, yeah, I know that, but I want to use `ListView`. Also in `ListView` we can use `ViewCell` that provides ripple effect that I cannot achieve in `CollectioView`.

Comment: then just call your VM method from the event handler, or use EventToCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will be moderately lengthy, but you will not find it anywhere else. I have tried for 2 days.

This answer is lengthy because I have demonstrated 3 things:

- Binding `ItemAppearing` to `Command` and then incrementally loading items.
- Selecting an Item from `ListView` and displaying it.
- Showing animation while loading new items incrementally.

In **MVVM**, **ViewModel** is supposed to be ignorant of the **View**. Hence **ViewModel** must not know if the `ListView` inside the **View** is scrolled to the last item or whether **LoadMoreItems** should be called on scrolling.

We need to convert `ItemAppearing` Event to `Command` and Bind this Command to the `ItemAppearing` event.

For this purpose we need to install **Xamarin.CommunityToolkit** Nuget Package. This package is supported by **.NetFoundation**, **Xamarin Community** and **Microsoft**, and is authored by **Microsoft**. This is the official package and is necessary for most of the advanced Xamarin.Forms. Check more on Nuget.org, Download latest stable release: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit (Install in all your projects Shared, Android, iOS, UWP, WPF, Tizen, etc)

**Assume your Model:**

```cs
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Now in your XAML**

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             ...
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit">

<StackLayout>
    <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsLoading}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding JobsList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedJob}">
            <ListView.Behaviors>
                <xct:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemAppearing"
                                            Command="{Binding LoadMoreItemsCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding ItemVisibilityEventArgs}"/>
            </ListView.Behaviors>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Id}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**In your code behind set BindingContext to instance of the ViewModel**

```cs
public partial class ListPage : ContentPage
{
    ListPageViewModel ListPageVM;

    public JobsListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListPageVM = new ListPageViewModel();
        BindingContext = ListPageVM;
    }
}
```

**In Your ViewModel**

```cs
public class ListPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Models.Job> JobsList 
    { 
        get { return jobsList; }
        set { jobsList = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(JobsList)); }
    }

    public ICommand LoadMoreItemsCommand { get; private set; }

    // Used to show Loading Animation in Refresh View
    public bool IsLoading 
    { 
        get { return isLoading; }
        set { isLoading = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsLoading)); } 
    }

    public Models.Job SelectedJob
    {
        get { return selectedJob; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                selectedJob = value;
                var page = Application.Current.MainPage;
                page.DisplayAlert("Alert", $"Selected: {selectedJob.JobTitle}", "OK");
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedJob));
            }
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<Models.Job> jobsList;
    Models.Job selectedJob;
    bool isLoading;

    public ListPageViewModel()  // ViewModel Constructor
    {
        // Initialize your List
        JobsList = new ObservableCollection<Models.Job>
        {
            new Models.Job() { Id = 0001, Title = "Product Manager" },
            new Models.Job() { Id = 0002, Title = "Senior Executive" },
        }

        LoadMoreItemsCommand = new Command<ItemVisibilityEventArgs>(
            execute: async (ItemVisibilityEventArgs args) => 
            {
                if ((args.Item as Models.Job).Id >= JobsList[JobsList.Count - 1].Id)
                {
                    IsLoading = true;

                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        JobsList.Add(new Models.Job()
                        {
                            Id = JobsList.Count + 1, JobTitle = JobsList[i].Title
                        });
                    }
                    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(2000); // Fake delay
                    IsLoading = false;
                }
            });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you add (to your question) more details about what you are trying to do.

The following technique blurs the line between "what View does" and "what ViewModel does" - and "tightly couples" your View and your ViewModel - it is possible that there is a better way to approach your goal. Nevertheless, this is a useful technique to know, so I'll show it.

---

Details for Jason's comment "call your VM method from event handler".

Add a public method to your VM:

```
public class MyVM
{
    public void MyMethod() {
        // whatever you need to do to prepare the item.
    }
}
```

In LoadMoreItems, call that method:

```
((MyVM)BindingContext).MyMethod();
```

Add parameters as needed.

If you need to "call back" to a method in your View, do that via an action parameter:

```
public void MyMethod(Action<...> action) {
    ...
    action(...);
}
```

For more details, google C# passing an Action as a parameter.

---

There are other techniques for communicating between View and ViewModel - search for more info on that topic.