# Load 12 items at a time and another 12 on scrolling

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to load 12 items when the list page is open and when the user scroll it will show the other 12 items. I was trying to use "Xamarin.Forms.Extended.InfiniteScrolling" package but xamarin nuget manager showing no package found maybe it is removed from xamarin forms. I'm providing my code here.

**xaml code**

```
            <ListView x:Name="listview2" HasUnevenRows="True"  IsVisible="false" ItemSelected="listview2_ItemSelected" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="18">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding prod_img}" TextColor="#289" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="80"
                       WidthRequest="80" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding prod_name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"  Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding prod_price}" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="1" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>



            <CollectionView SelectionMode="Single" x:Name="listview" SelectionChanged="listview_SelectionChanged"  IsVisible="true" RemainingItemsThreshold="4"
                            RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreCommand}"
                ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="18">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding prod_img}" TextColor="#289" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="80"
                       WidthRequest="20" />
                            

                            <Label Text="{Binding prod_name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Rs." TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding prod_price}" TextColor="Black"  LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        
                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>

                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            </CollectionView>
```

**Xaml.cs code**

```
public partial class import : ContentPage
    {
        
        public import()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            var jo = filelist().Result;
            
            var listView = new ListView ();

            listView.ItemAppearing += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                var items = listView.ItemsSource as IList;

                if (items == null
                    || items.Count == 0)
                    return;

                if (e.Item != items[items.Count - 1])
                    return;

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The end of the list, load more!");
            };

            listview.ItemsSource = jo;
                    listview2.ItemsSource = jo;    
            }


       


            private Task<List<csv>> filelist()
        {
            var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MainPage)).Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Todolist.WP.csv");
            List<csv> lstSample = new List<csv>();
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                
                if (reader != null)
                {

                    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
                    {
                        while (csvReader.Read())
                        {
                            lstSample.Add(new csv
                            {
                                //prod_id = csvReader.GetField<string>(0),
                                prod_name = csvReader.GetField<string>(2),
                                prod_img = csvReader.GetField<string>(18),
                                prod_price = csvReader.GetField<int>(13),
                                prod_desc = csvReader.GetField<string>(3),
                                prod_m_w = csvReader.GetField<string>(6),
                                Prod_cate= csvReader.GetField<string>(5)
                            });
                            //var todoItem = (task)BindingContext; 
                        }  
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return Task.FromResult(lstSample);
        }
```

Comment: CollectionView has built in incremental loading - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#load-data-incrementally

Comment: How is your `LoadMoreCommand` implemented, can you provide the corresponding code?

Comment: I tried to implement LoadMore command but it didn't work so I removed it

Comment: As stated in the link to the official document provided by Jason, "Data can also be loaded incrementally by binding the 'RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand' to an ICommand implementation in the viewmodel." You should determine whether the command you bind is valid.

Comment: Is there an example that can help me because I'm stuck here ..... Let me know if you need full code

Comment: You can refer to the answer in the thread: ["How to implement Loading Incrementally (ItemAppearing) Items in ListView using MVVM in Xamarin Forms?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68423498/how-to-implement-loading-incrementally-itemappearing-items-in-listview-using-m).